# Angular2 - Material2 - Custom Checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material2

I'm working on creating a custom checkbox based on the angular material2 project. Everything *seems* to be working at first but when I update model values in code, the checkbox does not un-check even though angular registers the change.  See the  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fGhut3sC2GePP6j4x1pd?p=preview) for a demo.

The relevant code to update the model values is:

```
private _parentValue:bool = false;
get parentValue()
{
    return this._parentValue;
}
set parentValue(val)
{
    this._parentValue = coerceBooleanProperty(val);

    this.value1 = this._parentValue;
    this.value2 = this._parentValue;
    this.value3 = this._parentValue;
}
```

I apologize in advance if I have done something incorrect here as this is my first time posting to stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite `writeValue` method as follows:

```
writeValue(value: T) {
    if (isDefined(value)) {
        this._value = value;
    }
}
```

where `isDefined` is a function like

```
export function isDefined(val: any): boolean {
  return val !== null && val !== undefined;
}
```

This way your control can consume `false` value

**[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zdqAdaPf8CKFvrqMIkpk?p=preview)**

Comment: Wow!  That was it.  I was under the impression that the 'writeValue' method was only used for setting the initial value of the control.  Thanks!